# AngularJs server call from controller using $resource service, not a function error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ngRoute for handling ui views

**app.js**

```
.state('customer.emenu-location',{
    name:'emenu-location',
    url:'/emenu-location',
    controller:'EmenuLocationController',
    templateUrl:'app/components/state/eMenu/emenu-location.html',
    resolve:{
        loadMyFiles:function($ocLazyLoad){
            return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                name:'emenu_components',
                files:[
                       'app/components/state/eMenu/eMenu-factory.js',
                       'app/components/state/eMenu/eMenu-location-association-controller.js'
                       ]
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Defining factory method for server call

**eMenu-factory.js**

```
.factory('BranchFactory', function($resource) {
    return $resource("/branch/status", {}, {
        post : { method : 'POST',  params : {}, isArray : false }
    });
})
```

Using the factory method in controller for server call

**eMenu-location-association-controller.js**

```
.controller('EmenuLocationController',function($state,$scope,BranchFactory){

    $scope.user = JSON.parse($localStorage.user);

    function getCustomer(){
        return $scope.user.customer.id;
    }

    $scope.requestData = {};
    $scope.requestData.customerId = getCustomer();
    $scope.requestData.status = "ACTIVE";

    BranchFactory.post($scope.requestData).$promise.then(function(data){
        $scope.branchList = data.content;
    });

});
```

But I am getting an exception, 
Error : BranchFactory.post is not a function

Every time I need to refresh the page to avoid this error. After refresh it's working fine no error shown.

[image]

Comment: Which is the right controller, "EmenuLocationController" or "EmenuLocationAssociationController"?

Comment: sorry!! EmenuLocationController is correct. I just modified the question

Comment: try annotating your injections like so:
.controller('EmenuLocationController',['$state', '$scope', 'BranchFactory', function($state,$scope,BranchFactory){ .....

Comment: All my controllers are working fine without injecting the services. Is that really matters?